# How to run a JavaScript file when a button is clicked in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, button, module

I have created a game with Phaser 3. I have it stored as a .js file in my working directory. I want the game to start when the start button is clicked on my .html index page. What am I doing wrong here?

The only thing I need to happen is for the game to run when the button is clicked, just as if I had included the script in the body

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- Title of our Page -->
    <title>Video Game</title>
    <!-- Phaser 3 link here -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS For our page -->
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 1000px !important;
            height: 750px !important;
        }
        script {
            width: 1000px !important;
            height: 750px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var skateGame = require('skateboarding.js');
    </script>
    <input type = "button" onclick = "skateGame" value = "Skateboarding" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably just missing parentheses after `skateGame`, i.e. `onclick = "skateGame()"`.

Comment: I'm not even sure the `require` would work.

Comment: @kshetline tried that, didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

in your **.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- Title of our Page -->
    <title>Video Game</title>
    <!-- Phaser 3 link here -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS For our page -->
    <style type="text/css">
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        width: 1000px !important;
        height: 750px !important;
      }
      script {
        width: 1000px !important;
        height: 750px !important;
      }
      #startGame {
        background-color: #4caf50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="startGame" value="Start Game" />
    <script src="skateBoarding.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in **skateBoarding.js**

```
var startButton = document
  .querySelector("#startGame")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.startGame();
  });

// Function that start game
startGame = () => {
  console.log("Game is starting");
};
```

let me know if this works.
and try to keep your html and js in separate files.

Comment: That is my goal, that is why I am doing this so I don’t have 1 file that is 1000 lines long. I will give this a shot real quick

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Is there any way I could remove the bar that displays at the top of the page? The button is still there inside of a long white bar

Comment: cheers, could you please share a snapshot of button. I don't get the bar, maybe something to do with browser.

Comment: @RobertSmith just updated the html file (added styling for button), update your html and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

By using onclick = "skateGame" your are asking javascript to do something with var skateGame wich does not make sense. Try :

```
 <button id="btn1" type="button"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

var myBtn= document.getElementById('btn1');

myBtn.onclick = function(){

    Your javascript code

}
</script>
```

Tell me if it works or not

Comment: You should probably expand on this a bit-- a link to an outside resource doesn't really constitute a complete answer.

Comment: sorry i'm new ^^

Comment: No problem-- if you would like to learn more about writing answers it might be useful to review [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Welcome to the site!

Comment: Yeah I had already been on W3Schools, and I tried that, it didn't work.